# Making sense out of $F$-structures and the notion of $F$-variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

For almost two years I have been trying to make sense out of several claims about varieties over nonalgebraically closed fields made in the first chapter of the textbook *Linear Algebraic Groups* by T.A. Springer.  Every now and then I go back to it and try to do it again, it always ends in failure.

Everyone says "Who cares?  Just learn schemes and do it the modern way" but the problem is a lot of related literature seems to avoid schemes and do it the way it's done in this book.  So I want to also avoid schemes for the time being.

**So far I have made sense out of the notion of an "affine $F$-variety."**  Here is the situation:

...............................

$k$ is an algebraically closed field, $F$ is a subfield, $A$ is a finitely generated reduced $k$-algebra. Let $X = \textrm{Spm } A$, and let $A_0$ be a finitely generated $F$-subalgebra for which $A \cong k \otimes_F A_0$.  An open set $U$ of $X$ is called $F$-open if its complement is the zero set of a collection of elements of $A_0$.

The $F$-open sets form a topology, and to each $F$-open $U$, define $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$ to be the set of functions $f: U \rightarrow k$ such that every point in $U$ has an $F$-open neighborhood $W \subseteq U$ together with functions $g, h \in A_0$ such that $h \neq 0$ on $W$ and $f = \frac{g}{h}$ on $W$.  An equivalent definition of $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$ is the following: let $D(f_i)$ be an open cover of $U_i$ by principal open sets with $f_i \in A_0$.  There is an exact sequence of $k$-vector spaces $$0 \rightarrow \mathcal O_X(U) \rightarrow \prod\limits_i A_{f_i} \rightarrow \prod\limits_{i,j} A_{f_if_j} $$ where we identify $\mathcal O_X(D_i)$ with $A_{f_i}$.  The right two vector spaces have $F$-structures coming from the localizations $(A_0)_{f_i}$, and the rightmost map is defined over $F$.  Hence the kernel is also defined over $F$, i.e. it has an $F$-subspace which when tensored with $k$ gets you back the kernel.  Since $\mathcal O_X(U)$ is isomorphic to this kernel, we obtain a canonical $F$-subspace of $\mathcal O_X(U)$, denoted $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$.  This shows that $$\mathcal O_X(U) \cong k \otimes_F \mathcal O_X^F(U)$$ and once you show this definition is independent of the choice of principal $F$-open cover $D(f_i)$, you get that $\mathcal O_X^F(D(f_i)) = (A_0)_{f_i}$ and $\mathcal O_X^F(X) = A_0$.

The variety $X$ together with the data of $F$-open sets $U$ and the rings $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$ is called an affine $F$-variety.

......................................

Now, here is what is said about defining an arbitrary variety over $F$:[image]

I have several questions about all this.  I would love for anyone who is good at this stuff to either answer the questions, or just explain their understanding of the whole thing.

> 1 .  In 1.6.15, each $U_i$ has a topology of $F$-open sets $W$, and for every such $W$ there is an $F$-algebra $\mathcal O_{X|U_i}^F(W)$ and an isomorphism $k \otimes_F \mathcal O_{X|U_i}^F(W) = \mathcal O_X(W)$.  In writing $U_i \cap U_j \rightarrow U_i$ is defined over $F$, the author means that the restriction of any $f \in \mathcal O_{X|U_i}^F(U_i)$ to $U_i \cap U_j$ lies in $\mathcal O_{X|U_j}^F(U_i \cap U_j)$, right?  He is **not* saying that $$\mathcal O_{X|U_i}^F(U_i \cap U_j) = \mathcal O_{X|U_j}^F(U_i \cap U_j)$$ right?

.

> 2 .  In 1.6.15 (or more generally 1.6.14), we are *not* in the business of defining an $F$-subalgebra $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$ of $\mathcal O_X(U)$ for each $F$-open set $U$, correct?  Or are we?  Springer mentions nothing of this.

In 1.6.15, the natural thing to do would be to set $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$ to be the set of functions $f: U \rightarrow k$ such that $f|U \cap U_i$ lies in $\mathcal O_{X|U_i}^F(U \cap U_i)$ for all $i$.

If we *were* defining $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$, I would expect to have something like $\mathcal O_X^F(U) = \mathcal O_{X|U_i}^F(U)$ if $U$ is an $F$-open set which is contained in $U_i$, but I haven't been able to prove this without the addition assumption/lemma that $k \otimes_F \mathcal O_X^F(U) = \mathcal O_X(U)$: with this assumption, we can easily show that $\mathcal O_X^F(U) \subseteq \mathcal O_{X|U_i}^F(U)$, and tensoring both with $k$ gets you $\mathcal O_X(U)$, hence they must be equal by faithful flatness.

> 3 .  In 1.6.15, suppose that $U$ is an $F$-open subset of $X$ (that is, $U \cap U_i$ is $F$-open in $U_i$ for all $i$) which is also affine.  Then the definition in 1.6.14 says that $(U, \mathcal O_{X|U})$ should be an affine $F$-variety.  In other words there should be some $F$-subalgebra $A_0$ of $\mathcal O_X(U)$, finitely generated over $F$, such such that $k \otimes_F A_0 = \mathcal O_X(U)$.

Where should such a thing come from?  Maybe it would be possible to define $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$ as in question 2 and show that $k \otimes_F \mathcal O_X^F(U) = \mathcal O_X(U)$.

**Example: The projective line $\mathbb P^1$**

Essentially the only example I have in mind is projective space.  Let $X = \mathbb{P}^1$, and let $U_0, U_1$ be the usual affine open covering.  Then $\mathcal O_X(U_0)$ is the ring of functions $k[\frac{X_1}{X_0}]$.  Likewise for $\mathcal O_X(U_0)$.  Both $U_0, U_1$ are affine $F$-varieties.  For example $\mathcal O_X(U_0)$ has $F$-structure $F[\frac{X_1}{X_0}]$.  Now $U_0 \cap U_1$ is principal $F$-open in both $U_0$ and in $U_1$, and we can see that $\mathcal O_{X|U_0}^F(U_0 \cap U_1) = F[\frac{X_1}{X_0}]_{\frac{X_1}{X_0}}$.  Basically you are localizing $k[T]$ at the element $T$.  But clearly $$\mathcal O_{X|U_0}^F(U_0 \cap U_1) = F[\frac{X_1}{X_0}]_{\frac{X_1}{X_0}} =  F[\frac{X_0}{X_1}]_{\frac{X_0}{X_1}} = \mathcal O_{X|U_1}^F(U_0 \cap U_1)$$ which is related to what I asked in my first question.

Comment: Take a gander at Milne's book where he explains the connection between Springer's language and the modern laguage in his book: http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf, appendix B.b. You may also wish to use Milne's book anyways- "everybody" has a pretty good point.